# Setup Int32MultiArray in micro-ROS arduino library (ROS2)

Tags: ros, arduino, multiarray

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.
I just started with ROS2 and I'm trying to send a couple of sensor datas form my microcontroller to my ROS2 system using the micro-ROS library in the arduino IDE --> C++.
Can someone give me an example how to setup an Int32MultiArray in the micro-ROS arduino library (ROS2)? I'm struggeling a lot. So basically I'd like to send an 2x5 Array of int32.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378021/setup-int32multiarray-in-micro-ros-arduino-library-(ros2)/) by [B00M3R](https://answers.ros.org/users/74295/b00m3r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When dealing with sequences in micro-ROS you have to assign memory and set `capacity` and `size`. An example [here](https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/blob/fbb4af8bb5361f5a9fac81633dd2d6ab40d7b044/examples/micro-ros_tf_publisher/micro-ros_tf_publisher.ino#L114).

If you need detailed information, please open an issue in the Github repo and share your code.

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2021-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [B00M3R](https://answers.ros.org/users/74295/b00m3r/) on 2021-05-10**:
Thanks Pablo,

this was the right hint I needed.

```
//DummyData
```

uint32_t senors [2][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10}};

std_msgs__msg__Int32MultiArray * msg_sensors;
msg_sensors =  std_msgs__msg__Int32MultiArray__create();

msg_sensors->layout.dim.data = (std_msgs__msg__MultiArrayDimension*)malloc(2*sizeof(std_msgs__msg__MultiArrayDimension));

msg_sensors->data.data = (int32_t*)malloc(sizeof(senors));
msg_sensors->data.capacity = 1;
msg_sensors->data.size = sizeof(senors)/sizeof(int32_t);
memcpy(msg_sensors->data.data , senors, sizeof(senors));

rcl_publish(&pub_Encoder, msg_sensors, NULL);

*sorry but the code formating doesn't work

**Comment by [Sarwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/78794/sarwan/) on 2021-08-23**:
Hi, I am having issues subscribing to the Int64MultiArray msgs. have you tried it. if yes could you please share the code

**Comment by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) on 2021-08-24**:
Answered here: https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/issues/413